# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.UserTokenProvider

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am getting highlighted issue at  below code

```
     var restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                    .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                    .WithBaseUri("https://management.azure.com/")
                    .WithCredentials(creds)
                    .Build();
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
// getting issue in below code
       await restClient.Credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(message, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
```

**Error:**

> Method not found:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials>
>   Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.UserTokenProvider.LoginByDeviceCodeAsync(System.String,
>   System.String,
>   Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings,
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache,
>   System.Func`2)'.

I have referenced below dll with latest version

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory --> Version 4.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Install `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent->1.24.1` with .net framework `4.6.1` and it will work fine. Refer to this [article](https://www.re-mark-able.net/secure-logic-app-htpp-triggers/).
[image]

Comment: I am already referencing same package with its latest version

Comment: I have changed project type from .Net Framework to .Net Core and referenced all latest dlls.  It's working fine now without any issues.